# What is the maximum URL length allowed by the web server of stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, tags, hyperlinks

I want to know what the maximum number of tags allowed in a SO url is. I try a longish url (like `/tagged/a+OR+b+OR+...`) to select only the questions I am interested in, and I get a "Bad Request" response...

I suppose the question could be rephrased as:

**What is the maximum url length allowed by the web server of stack overflow?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If you use the querystring method, it can be much longer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=c%23%20java

versus

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23%20java

Comment: Then what is the answer in each case?

Comment: Thanks. I supposed that's the querystring method I was looking for. By the way, it's a pity that I have to compute this url manually. It would be cool if there was a simple link to that url on my profile page.

Comment: @olivier your user page tags are linked to a per-user tag search for you -- try clicking them

Comment: where is that? If one of my tags is "Python", there is a link to all questions tagged "Python". But I have about 20 tags. I want an url of the form: "/questions/tagged?tagnames=tag1+OR+tag2+OR+tag3+...". For now, I have to construct it manually, right? I'd love SO to construct that URL for me.

Comment: assuming that the parameter name, "tagnames", was not known: is there a way to discover it? Or does a list or doument exist with this information?

Answer (score 3):

For the [path method](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50847/what-is-the-maximum-url-length-allowed-by-the-web-server-of-stack-overflow/50950#50950) (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags)

With a query of ≥261 chars, the server returns "400 Bad Request".

With a query of ≥242 chars, the server returns a blank page.

With a query of ≥223 chars, the "workin on ur problemz" page appears.