# An RSS feed is included for wildcard tag pages, this link gives a 400 error

Tags: bug, status-completed

If I click on one of my favourite tags `.net*` I go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net~. There is an RSS icon for this multiple tag feed: https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/.net+or+.net-3.5+or+.net-2.0+or+.net-4.0+or+.net-1.1+or+.net-3.5-sp1+or+.net-3.0+or+.net-ria-services+or+.netremoting+or+.net-micro-framework+or+.net-4.0-beta-2+or+.net-generics+or+.net-1.0+or+.net-remoting+or+.net-assembly+or+.net-reflector+or+.nettiers+or+.net-framework-version+or+.net-4.0-rc1+or+.net-internals

Which returns 400 "Bad Request"

The link comes from a `<link>` in the HTML:

```
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml"
          title="Feed of questions tagged .net or .net-3.5 or .net-2.0 or .net-4.0
                 or .net-1.1 or .net-3.5-sp1 or .net-3.0 or .net-ria-
                 or .netremoting or .net-micro-framework or .net-4.0-beta-2 
                 or .net-generics or .net-1.0 or .net-remoting or .net-assembly 
                 or .net-reflector or .nettiers or .net-framework-version or .net-4.0-rc1
                 or .net-internals" 
           href="/feeds/tag/.net+or+.net-3.5+or+.net-2.0+or+.net-4.0+or+.net-1.1+or+.net-3.5-sp1+or+.net-3.0+or+.net-ria-services+or+.netremoting+or+.net-micro-framework+or+.net-4.0-beta-2+or+.net-generics+or+.net-1.0+or+.net-remoting+or+.net-assembly+or+.net-reflector+or+.nettiers+or+.net-framework-version+or+.net-4.0-rc1+or+.net-internals" />
```

Comment: Toooooo maaaaaaaannnyyyyyyyyyy taaaaaaaaaaaaaags. Muuuuuuuuuch tooooooooo looooooooong. Your poor browser ;)

Comment: @Ladybug: More a case of the poor server (which is where the request is rejected). MOre little sympathy for the server: that's where the link came from :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently changed how wildcards are handled at various levels, now [that feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=.net*) will look like this:

```
<title type="text">active questions tagged .net* - Stack Overflow</title>
<link rel="self" href="https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=.net*" type="application/atom+xml" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=.net*&amp;sort=active" type="text/html" />
```

Notice the link to the feed won't be expanded, so the link at the bottom of the page is much cleaner as well: `"newest .net* questions feed"`.  This has 2 effects:

1. It's much cleaner, and the long URL problems are avoided.
2. Your feed link will include new tags as they're added, since you're not looking at the expansion list of when the page was rendered (and subsequently the RSS link you used from that).

To update you feed just visit [the wildcard tag page again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net*?sort=newest) and use the feed link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just convert it to the other form.

See:
[What is the maximum URL length allowed by the web server of stack overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50847/what-is-the-maximum-url-length-allowed-by-the-web-server-of-stack-overflow/50950#50950)